# How to force close a ngx-contextmenu in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-contextmenu

In my angular project, I have an `ngx-contextmenu`.

I have a component, and in the component's template there is a code like:

```
<div... [contextMenu]="basicMenu">
<context-menu>.....
</div>
```

Now, my component, which has this context menu, is destroyed after a while!

But, the context menu is still on the screen even though the component is destroyed!!

So, my question is, how to force close this context menu when my component is destroyed?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `ngOnDestroy`

Comment: @Aluan Haddad but what to write in ngOnDestroy to close the ngx-contextmenu???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [ContextMenuService](https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu/blob/master/projects/ngx-contextmenu/src/lib/contextMenu.service.ts) which has 
`closeAllContextMenus` method. You can invoke it in `OnDestroy` function

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy  {

  @ViewChild(ContextMenuComponent) public basicMenu: ContextMenuComponent;

  constructor(private _contextMenuService: ContextMenuService) {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this._contextMenuService.closeAllContextMenus({ eventType: 'cancel'});
  }
}
```